# Is this kind of code prone to SQL injection?

Tags: sql-injection

I am doing a project for my school and I am task to debug all of the issues found using the application call HPE Fortify. The report generated by the application only indicates the code below prone to SQL injection:

```
        String sql = " select Distinct p1.desc1,p2.desc2 from parameter  p1"
          +" inner join  parameter p2"
          +" on p1.ParaCode1='CR_DERIVE' and p1.ParaCode2=p2.Desc2"
          +" inner join parameter p3"
          + " on p2.ParaCode3=p3.ParaCode1 and p3.ParaCode3=p2.Desc2"
          +" where p2.paracode1='ATTRIBUTE'"
          + " and p2.ParaCode2='" + ddl_attribute.SelectedValue + "'";
```

But not the codes below:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Paracode2 FROM Parameter WHERE Paracode1 = 'PROGMGR' AND Desc1 = '" + login + "' AND Status = 'A' ";
```

I would like to know the reason why as I am unclear regarding SQL injection and I am new to this. Thanks for the response

Comment: My rule of thumb: if you're using string manipulation and not query parameters, you're probably vulnerable. Just use query parameters.

Comment: Both of those are equally vulnerable. The application is wrong. Just follow one rule - *Don't concatenate SQL, **especially with user input*** - and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're concatenating some application variables into your SQL query string, so the safety depends on how those variables' values were set. Did they come from some untrusted input? Or were they set from some safe application data?

If HPE Fortify has analyzed your code and knows how your `login` variable was assigned its value, it may be able to tell that it's safe to use in an SQL expression. Whereas it may not be able to make that conclusion about the `SelectedValue` variable, so it assumes it's unsafe and therefore could cause an SQL vulnerability.

The Perl language does something similar, without the use of a tool like HPE Fortify. Every Perl variable is either "tainted" or "untainted" depending on where it got its value. So you can tell whether a variable is safe to use in SQL, or in eval() or other possible code-injection situations. It's a pity more languages don't support something similar.

But I agree with other commenters that you should learn to use query parameters. It's easy and it's safe. And you can stop getting eyestrain figuring out if you've balanced your quotes-within-quotes correctly.

Your code sample looks like it might be Java. Here's an example in Java:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Paracode2 FROM Parameter"
       + " WHERE Paracode1 = 'PROGMGR' AND Desc1 = ? AND Status = 'A' ";
```

Notice the `?` placeholder for the parameter has no single-quotes around it within the SQL string. You must not put SQL quotes around the placeholder.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.PreparedStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, login);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

For more information to help you understand SQL injection, you might like my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies), or the video of me delivering that talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VldxqTejybk

Comment: Thanks for giving me a more indepth guide! Really appreciate it alot :)